# Azure Service Fabric Remoting with generic parameter

Tags: c#, azure, generics, azure-service-fabric, .net-remoting

I am sending a generic parameter in my Service Fabric application method via service remoting.

my Interface is as follows:

```
public interface IMyServiceRemoting : IService
{
   Task<String> GetMessageFromServer<T>(T hint)// a hint could be of byte[] or string or any object
}
```

While I am getting

> System.ArgumentException: "The service interface 'ServiceRemoting.Interfaces.IMyServiceRemoting`1[[System.Object, mscorlib, version = 4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, publicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'is using generic. **Generic interface cannot be remoted**".

I am unable to understand why I can't use generics. 
Kindly help with proper explanation.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-services-and-actors-dotnet/issues/21

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985580/service-fabric-with-generic-services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply can't. It's not possible to do that, as soap does not support this. See this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/79585667-6b97-4ce4-93fa-3a4dcc7a9b86/wcf-and-generics?forum=wcf), which mentions how to get around generics, by creating an intermediate local object that is called and casts the object before calling the WCF operation.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked before. The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992513/5946937) is from an SF team member.

> So in your case, no, generics are not yet supported. But this is a
>   limitation of that specific service communication stack, not of
>   services in general, and of course you can use [any communication stack](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services/)
>   you want